# How to change my content-type of a json file in JS

Tags: javascript, json, file

I have been working with a Json file and javascript. While opening the file I recieved this error

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0`

After Some research I found out that my JSON file's content-type is actually set to html. But now I don't know how to change the content-type of my file to json.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbzvM.png)

```js
function generateRow(){
  console.log("WORKING");

  fetch('./addplaylist.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
  
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are getting back an error page or something that is not JSON. Did you look at what was in the response back?

Comment: If you do `fetch('./addplaylist.json').then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))` what do you get logged?

Comment: the content-type is irrelevant. Calling `reponse.json()` will parse the text as JSON regardless of the content-type.

Comment: But the problem is that the response isn't actually JSON. Use the Network tab to see the raw response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I ran a search 'json change the content-type' & got back 6K+ results. I recommend you do the same because you may find an answer to your question there _ Good Luck